# Get object by ID eg SQL WHERE predicate in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I had a look at Entity Framework, get object by ID.

I can't get that to work.

I specifically want the

```
WHERE [Extent1].[CatId] = 1
```

as I don't want to return everything that filter it as in

```
using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())  
{
    IQueryable<Project> projects = db.Projects; // Get all
    var p =  (from i in db.Projects where i.Id == ProjectID select i);
    Console.WriteLine("Project #  {0} added and Named:{1} ", ProjectID, p.First().Name);
    Assert.IsNotNull(projects.First().Name);
}
```

So what I am looking for in SQL terms is

```
SELECT *   
FROM Projects 
WHERE id = 1
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is.  Are you just looking for `db.Projects.Single(p => p.Id == ProjectID)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use LINQ fluent syntax:

```
var project = db.Projects.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == ProjectId);
```

[Great LINQ reference and examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)